# Length units converter

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, asp.net-core

I am creating a very small application to demonstrate solid principles and also a brief implementation of a builder pattern, does anyone have any feedback as to how this could be improved or how it breaks the solid principles? The app is a small app that just converts units, e.g. yards to meters, inches to cms.

**Interface**

```
public interface IConverter
{
    double ConversionRate { get; set; }
    string[] ConvertedUnits { get; set; }
    string DisplayText { get; set; }

    string[] Convert(string input);
}
```

**Class implementing interface**

```
 public class Converter : IConverter
    {
        public double ConversionRate { get; set; }
        public string[] ConvertedUnits { get; set; }
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }

        public Converter(double conversionRate, string[] convertedUnits, string displayText)
        {
            ConversionRate = conversionRate;
            ConvertedUnits = convertedUnits;
            DisplayText = displayText;
        }

        public string[] Convert(string input)
        {
            if (!input.Contains('\n'))
            {
                double d = double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * ConversionRate;

                string[] array = new string[1];
                array[0] = d.ToString();

                return array;
            }
            else
            {
                double[] doubles = new double[input.Split('\n').Count()];

                for (int i = 0; i < input.Split('\n').Count(); i++)
                {
                    double value = double.Parse(input.Split('\n')[i]);
                    doubles[i] = value;

                    string.Format("{0}", value * ConversionRate);
                }

                string[] strings = new string[doubles.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < input.Split('\n').Length; i++)
                {
                    strings[i] = string.Format("{0}", doubles[i] * ConversionRate);
                }

                return strings;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Builder (abstract class)**

```
public abstract class ConverterBuilder
    {
        protected double _conversionRate;
        protected string[] _convertedUnits;
        protected string _displayText;

        public ConverterBuilder AddConversionRate(double conversionRate)
        {
            _conversionRate = conversionRate;
            return this;
        }

        public ConverterBuilder AddConversionRate(string[] convertedUnits)
        {
            _convertedUnits = convertedUnits;
            return this;
        }

        public ConverterBuilder AddDisplayText(string displayText)
        {
            _displayText = displayText;
            return this;
        }

        public Converter Build()
        {
            return new Converter(_conversionRate, _convertedUnits, _displayText);
        }

    }
```

**Builder implementing abstract builder class**

```
public class UnitConverterBuilder : ConverterBuilder
{
    public UnitConverterBuilder()
    {

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Convert(string text, double conversionRate)
{
    Converter converter = new UnitConverterBuilder()
    .AddConversionRate(conversionRate)
    .Build();

    string output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < converter.Convert(text).Count(); i++)
    {
        output += converter.Convert(text)[i] + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    return Content(output);

}
```

**View**

Enter values to convert

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Convert" method="post">
    <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    <select name="conversionRate">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="0.9144">Yards to Meters</option>
        <option value="2.54">Inches To Centimeters</option>
    </select>
    <button>Convert</button>
</form>
```

The app is built using .net core, any feedback greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: _Builder implementing abstract builder class_ - this one is empty and not abstract - did you forget to copy/paste something?

Comment: What’s your use-case? What benefit does having an interface and a builder class provide? For that matter, what benefit does having a *class* provide? Why not have a static `Convert` function? Lastly, I’m puzzled that `Convert` takes a `string` and returns `string[]`. It would be necessary to clarify this contract but I’d generally expect a signature of the form `double Convert(double input)` or (as suggested) `static double Convert(double input, double conversionRate)`. Such a method adheres much closer to SOLID than your implementation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph _What benefit does having an interface and a builder class provide_ - how about dependency injection?

Comment: @t3chb0t My suggested static `Convert` function deals perfectly well with dependency injection. There are tons of ways of implementing dependency injection, it doesn’t necessitate any of the boilerplate shown here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph nothing `static` is DI-friendly. How do you want to replace it for testing? There's no way you can inject anything else in its place.

Comment: @t3chb0t Just pass a different method as a delegate. Or, better yet: don’t, because there’s no need to mock the conversion during testing. Instead, inject an appropriate conversion by passing a `conversionRate` of your choice. *That’s* the only dependency here that is worth replacing. In other words: don’t blindly apply principles without first checking whether they’re being applied appropriately. Testing for its own sake is useless, it should be applied to solve specific problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The S in SOLID

Since you mention SOLID, I'd like to point out that `IConverter` has too many responsibilities:

1. It converts from one unit to another.
2. It splits input on newlines
3. It contains display-related information.

The first is exactly what you'd expect a converter to do.

The second is better left to the caller. If they need to convert multiple inputs they can simply call `IConverter.Convert` multiple times. You already need to do that anyway if you've got a comma-separated string or an array of inputs, so why should the conversion logic contain a special case for newlines?

The third should be the responsibility of the UI layer of your program, where you can take care of things like localization and visualization.

#### Scalable design

Another issue with this design is that it's not very scalable. Every 'unit-to-unit' conversion requires a different converter instance. With just inches, centimeters and millimeters, you already need 6 converters: `inch->cm`, `inch->mm`, `cm->inch`, `cm->mm`, `mm->inch` and `mm->cm`. For 10 units, you'll need 90.

A better design would define each unit in terms of a single base unit. For example, taking centimeter as base: `Unit("inch", 2.54)`, `Unit("cm", 1.0)`, `Unit("mm", 0.1)`. That gives you enough information to be able to convert from any of these units to any other. Adding another unit now only requires a single new piece of information.

#### Other issues

- Those `IConverter` properties should not have public setters - you don't want other code to be able to modify the conversion rate of a converter!
- There's no documentation, and several things aren't clear from the code itself: the purpose of that `ConvertedUnits` array, or why the return type of `Convert` is an array of strings, among other things.
- The builder contains two `AddConversionRate` methods - one of them should be renamed to `AddConvertedUnits`.
- This has been pointed out already: you're repeating work by calling `input.Split('\n')` too many times. But the same goes for the controller code: you're also repeatedly calling `converter.Convert`.
- A related issue is that of code duplication: in `Convert`, the `if` part is doing the same as the `else` part, minus the string-splitting. However, if the input does not contain any newlines then `string.Split` will return an array with one element, so the `else` part alone is sufficient.

#### Simplicity

Finally, I agree with what Konrad Rudolph said in the comments: what's the benefit of using an interface and a builder here? This sort of design is very useful when, for example, you're working with a database: it allows you to swap `DatabaseConnection` for `SimulatedDatabaseConnection` while testing. But can you think of a situation where being able to swap `Converter` for another implementation would be useful?

Keep in mind that this extra flexibility doesn't come for free - there's more code to maintain, and more complex designs are also more difficult to maintain. So first ask yourself: do I need this kind of flexibility, and is it worth the cost?

In this case, a simpler design will likely suffice:

```
public class Unit
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public double Ratio { get; }

    public Unit(string name, double ratio)
    {
        Name = name;
        Ratio = ratio;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a value from the current unit to the specified unit.
    /// </summary>
    public double Convert(double value, Unit toUnit)
    {
        return (value * Ratio) / toUnit.Ratio;
    }
}
```

It makes sense to combine that with a `Unit GetUnit(string name)` 'factory method', so you don't need to modify calling code when adding a unit. `GetUnit` could load units from a database, a file, or simply contain a few hard-coded ones - details that calling code shouldn't need to worry about.

A `Unit[] AvailableUnits()` method (or property) would also be useful, if you want to show users which units they can convert between. That's better than having the user type out the unit name, and then wonder why `"centimeter"` doesn't work but `"cm"` does.

```
// Basic conversion, inch to cm:
var convertedValue = GetUnit("inch").Convert(value, toUnit: GetUnit("cm"));

// Your controller code, refactored - including some error handling:
var fromUnit = AvailableUnits[fromUnitIndex];
var toUnit = AvailableUnits[toUnitIndex];
return string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
    input.Split('\n')
        .Select(part =>
        {
            if (double.TryParse(part, out var value))
                return fromUnit.Convert(value, toUnit).ToString();
            else
                return $"Invalid input: '{part}'";
        }));
```

Comment: In your final comment where you hard-code 'inch and 'cm'  into the getunit method how would you get these values from the ui? E.g. a from unit and a to unit. What I mean is this data would need to come from the ui and then be passed to a data access layer (if a db was used)

Comment: I'd show a list of available units to the user (hence `AvailableUnits`) and pass the chosen unit names back into the controller's `Convert` method via parameters: `public IActionResult Convert(string input, string fromUnitName, string toUnitName)`.

Comment: Thank you!! In terms of the factory pattern to get the data (with hard coded values lets say) would you simply create a factory class that returned a unit object based on the name provided. Isn't the factory pattern normally concerned with creation rather than getting or am I wrong

Comment: If you only need units in this particular controller then a `GetUnit` and `AvailableUnits` method in the controller itself is sufficient. If other controllers also need to work with units then you'd move those methods to a shared model. Just because this approach matches the factory pattern (depending on how you view things) doesn't mean you need a separate `Factory` class, or that this method should be named `UnitFactory`.

Answer (score 10):

Only targeting `public string[] Convert(string input)`

- Because this is a `public` method you should validate the input. Right now if one passes `null` this will throw an `ArgumentNullException` which isn't that bad but the stacktrace belongs to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains()` which you should hide.
  Just testing against `null` or using string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` will do the trick.
- You are calling `input.Split('\n')` many many times. It would be much better to call it once and store the result in a variable.
- Don't use `Count()` method on an array, Using `Count()` use the `Length` property instead.
- You should use the overloaded [`Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) method which takes a `[StringSplitOptions][2]` enum like `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.
- Instead of using `double.Parse()` you should consider to use `double.TryParse()` which won't throw an exception if the current string doesn't represent a double like e.g a letter.
- This `string.Format("{0}", value * ConversionRate);` can be safely removed because the result isn't assigned to anything.
- Instead of returning a `string[]` you should consider to use an `IEnumerable<string` or better just an `IEnumerable<double>` which is more straightforward. Sure that means you need to change your interface as well.
- Using a `foreach` will make the code shorter because you won't need to check for `\n`.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

**string version**

```
public IEnumerable<string> Convert(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        yield break;
    }
    var values = input.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        double current;
        if (double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out current))
        {
            yield return (current * ConversionRate).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**double version**

```
    public IEnumerable<double> Convert(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            yield break;
        }
        var values = input.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            double current;
            if (double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out current))
            {
                yield return (current * ConversionRate);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Ok, I need to target `Controller.Convert()` as well

This is really really bad:

> ```
> string output = "";
> for (int i = 0; i < converter.Convert(text).Count(); i++)
> {
>     output += converter.Convert(text)[i] + Environment.NewLine;
> }
>
> return Content(output);
> ```

Assume you have `text = "\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5.......\n1000"` then your code will once call `converter.Convert()` at
`for (int i = 0; i < converter.Convert(text).Count(); i++)`
which results in `Count() = 1000` hence the loop will be executed 1000 times which calls `converter.Convert(text)` 1000 times.
In addition using `output +=` on strings will lead to very bad performance because each time a new string object is created because strings are immutable.
Better use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Assuming you use the `IEnumerable<double> Convert()` this will lead to

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
    foreach (var value in converter.Convert(text))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(value.ToString());
    }

    return Content(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: `Count()` Avoids iteration if the type is `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>`. Array implements the former so it won't be fully iterated. See [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1314)

Comment: @RobH I know, but at least a softcast with a null check will be avoided.

Comment: @Heslacher What is a softcast? Don't think I've ever seen that terminology in any language specification ever. There is a virtual call involved certainly which might have marginal overhead (although HotSpot would optimise it away, not sure how good RyuJit is these days), but nothing is casted there as far as I can see. As it stands the claim is completely wrong and will make people worry about performance for no reason (there's a big difference between a virtual call and iterating through a possibly gigantic array).

Comment: (Otherwise I completely agree with this answer, but this is such a big problem in my eyes that I had to downvote it, until it's fixed).

Comment: What I mean by softcast is using the `as` operator.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> public IActionResult Convert(string text, double conversionRate)
> {
>     Converter converter = new UnitConverterBuilder()
>     .AddConversionRate(conversionRate)
>     .Build();
> ```

Here you should use `IConverter converter = ...` instead of `Converter converter = ...`. That is the whole idea of having an interface. And maybe `ConverterBuilder.Build()` should return an `IConverter` interface instead of the `Converter` class?

---

I think your `Convert(...)` method lacks to deal with strings that are not parsable to double. It will throw a `FormatException` on the first invalid number string. So you must at least provide a `try-catch` block around the calls to `Convert()` in the calling method. Heslacher suggest using `double.TryGetValue()`, but does it IMO only halfway, because he just ignores strings that are not convertible. In that way the client has no idea of what went wrong where. Using Haslachers approach you need to do something like:

```
    double current;
    if (double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out current))
    {
        yield return (current * ConversionRate).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
       yield return double.NaN.ToString();
    }
```

or otherwise signal to the client that something went wrong, because if you enter a string with say 5 values and one is in invalid format you'll only get 4 back, but which 4?

---

I can't quite figure out why you declare `ConverterBuilder` as `abstract`? Why can't consumers use it as is? It is fully working and requires no extensions in derived objects to work properly. To give it any meaning you should make the methods `virtual` so subclasses can extent/alter the default behavior.

---

Further:

An abstract class with only non-virtual/non-abstract methods is only meaningful by letting subclasses extent the behavior:

```
  public class UnitConverterBuilder : ConverterBuilder
  {
    public UnitConverterBuilder()
    {

    }

    public UnitConverterBuilder AddSomethingElse(object somethingElse)
    {
      return this;
    }

  }
```

your method chaining can then become rather complicated and hard to read and understand:

```
  UnitConverterBuilder builder = new UnitConverterBuilder();
  IConverter converter = (builder
    .AddConversionRate(2.54)
    .AddDisplayText("Inches to cm") as UnitConverterBuilder)
    .AddSomethingElse("something else")
    .Build();
```

because the methods return the base class `ConverterBuilder`.

You can overcome this by defining the base class as:

```
  public abstract class ConverterBuilder<TSubClass> where TSubClass : ConverterBuilder<TSubClass>
  {
    protected double _conversionRate;
    protected string[] _convertedUnits;
    protected string _displayText;

    public virtual TSubClass AddConversionRate(double conversionRate)
    {
      _conversionRate = conversionRate;
      return this as TSubClass;
    }

    public virtual TSubClass AddConversionRate(string[] convertedUnits)
    {
      _convertedUnits = convertedUnits;
      return this as TSubClass;
    }

    public virtual TSubClass AddDisplayText(string displayText)
    {
      _displayText = displayText;
      return this as TSubClass;
    }

    public virtual IConverter Build()
    {
      return new Converter(_conversionRate, _convertedUnits, _displayText);
    }

  }
```

and `UnitConverterBuilder` as:

```
  public class UnitConverterBuilder : ConverterBuilder<UnitConverterBuilder>
  {
    public UnitConverterBuilder()
    {

    }

    public UnitConverterBuilder AddSomethingElse(object somethingElse)
    {
      // TODO: do something with somethingElse
      return this;
    }

  }
```

In this way your method chaining becomes straight forward and intuitive again:

```
  UnitConverterBuilder builder = new UnitConverterBuilder();
  IConverter converter = builder
    .AddConversionRate(2.54)
    .AddDisplayText("Inches to cm")
    .AddSomethingElse("something else")
    .Build();
```

But I think that allowing to extent a builder in this way violates the idea of the builder pattern, because a builder is supposed to implement a certain interface that is the contract between the builder and director. You don't relate to that part of the pattern at all?

You should be able to use the builder like this:

```
IBuilder builder = new UnitConverterBuilder(); //(or just: new ConverterBuilder();)
IConverter converter = builder.AddConversionRate(10).AddXXX()...Build();
```

where `IBuilder` is defined as:

```
public interface IBuilder 
{
  IBuilder AddConvertionRate(double rate);
  IBuilder AddXXX(...);
  ...
  IConverter Build();
}
```

---

**Update:**

As an answer to Matthwes question in his comment:

It's a step on the path: An interface is the abstraction or contract between the implementer and the client/consumer. So in principle your controller class should not know about the actual builder and converter implementations but fully rely on interfaces: `IConverterBuilder` which could be injected in the controllers constructor (in asp.net-core there are apis to do that from the startup class) and in the `Convert(string text, double conversionRate)` action it should call the apis (`Addxxx(), Addyyy, Build()`) of the injected builder `interface` to build the converter, but only know it as the contract: `IConverter`. In this way you implement both the Dependency Inversion and Dependency Injection principles.

Comment: Henrik- so in your first comment regarding returning IConverter instead of Converter is this so we adhere to dependency inversion in that we should depend on abstractions not concrete

Comment: @MatthewStott: see my update of the answer :-)